# ForEach doesn't update on view , when I append elements in my array, How can I do?

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, swiftui, mvvm

```
[MVVM]

struct HomeView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = HomeViewModel()

     ...

    var body: some View {
       ...
                

                        ForEach(viewModel.habitList, id: \.id) {
                            habit in HabitCellView(habit: habit)
                        }

                    ...
                
            }
        }
    }
}



class HomeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var habitList : [Habit] = [ ]

... }


struct Habit: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var hNum: Int
    var isCheck: Bool
    var date: Date
    var emoji: Emoji
    var title: String
    var category : String
    var contents: String
    var period:[Int] = Array<Int>(repeating: -1, count: 7)
    var isPublic: Bool
    var with:[Person]
    // var theme: Theme
}

struct AddHabitView: View {
    @State private var habitName = ""
    @State private var category = ""
    @State private var habitContent = ""
    @State private var isPublic = false
    @State private var inviteFriends = ""
    @State var selectedEmoji: Emoji?
    @State private var displayEmojiPicker = false
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = HomeViewModel()
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        ...
        

        }
        .navigationBarItems(
            trailing:
                Button(action: saveHabit) {
                    ...
                }
)
    
// append to habitList
    func saveHabit() {
        
        let habit = Habit(hNum: 0, isCheck: false, date: Date(), emoji: selectedEmoji ?? Emoji(value: "", name: "default"), title: habitName, category: category, contents: habitContent, isPublic: isPublic, with: [])

        viewModel.habitList.append(habit)

        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()

    }


}
```

The initial element value is displayed in view well by ForEach.

The saveHabit function adds a new Habit to the array without a problem.

But the view is not updated.

I've googled variously but couldn't find an answer.

1. Checked annotations like published.

2. I tried copying the viewModel's habitList when I created a new @State var habitListForView =[Habit]() and .onApear it.

Comment: Currently you have two different `viewModel` that have no relations to each other. 
One in `AddHabitView` and one in `HomeView` 
that should be **the only** one you need to pass around to the other views.
 In `AddHabitView`, use 
 `@ObservedObject var viewModel: HomeViewModel` and pass the model to it, either directly,
 eg `AddHabitView(viewModel: viewModel)` or using `@EnvironmentObject..` and `.environmentObject(viewModel)`